# Create a dataframe from an xml file

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, dataframe

i have a real (and maybe pretty stupid) problem to convert a xml-file into a dataframe from pandas. Im new in python and need some help. I trying a code from another thread and modificate it but it not works.

I want to iterate through this file:

```
<objects>
 <object id="123" name="some_string">
<object>
  <id>123</id>
  <site id="456" name="somename" query="some_query_as_string"/>
  <create-date>some_date</create-date>
  <update-date>some_date</update-date>
  <update-user id="567" name="User:xyz" query="some_query_as_string"/>
  <delete-date/>
  <delete-user/>
  <deleted>false</deleted>
  <system-object>false</system-object>
  <to-string>some_string_notifications</to-string>
</object>
<workflow>
  <workflow-type id="12345" name="WorkflowType_some_workflow" query="some_query_as_string"/>
  <validated>true</validated>
  <name>somestring</name>
  <exported>false</exported>
</workflow>
```

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.xml"
with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
    content = fp.read()
parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = ET.fromstring(content, parser=parser)

def xml2df(tree):
root = ET.XML(tree)
all_records = []
for i, child in enumerate(root):
    record ={}
    for subchild in child:
        record[subchild.tag] = subchild.text
        all_records.append(record)
    return pd.DataFrame(all_records)
```

Where is the problem? Please help :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the file location string to `ET.fromstring()`, which is not the actual contents of the file.  You need to read the contents of the file first, then pass that to `ET.fromstring()`.

```
path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.xml"
with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
    content = fp.read()

parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = ET.fromstring(content, parser=parser)
```

Comment: It indicates a raw string input.  In this case it is not necessary; I will remove it.

Comment: Well now he cant find the file and i get a FileNotFoundError. I edited the code.